# one Thread Pool for my whole android application

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin

like - network operation and bitmap manipulating an image loading and other kinds of work can I create a single `TheadPoolExecuter` for my whole application and execute on it.

if the answer is no -> why? and how to create `thread pool` for every single operation?

or if yes -> is performance problem occurs?

thanks in advance.

Comment: *Can I create a single TheadPoolExecuter for my whole application and execute on it* Yes it is fine, In fact I have seen source code from Google samples uses this approach.

Comment: Enzkie i also seen them but my confusion is not clear because google sample using two thead pool one for decoding and second for downloading . so why google used two thread pool insted of one.?

Comment: IMO they do that because they want to isolate long running tasks from those tasks that are faster to complete. Imagine you have 4 threads in your pool and suddenly 4 heavy network request are loaded to the pool first while a simple db query is currently pending, in that case that delays the simple request.

Comment: @Enzokie A better way to define the difference is CPU-bound tasks vs. blocking tasks. You certainly want a single threadpool for all CPU-bound work. For blocking calls you'll need more threads doing nothing. However, on Android you should just avoid blocking network APIs.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for that helpful pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of approach have advantages and disadvantages.

In case of single thread pool (singleton implementation, I suppose):
➕ you have one entry point to submit background task
➕ it easily to implement and control life cycle
➖ if you have a lot of different quick tasks and some long running task, long running tasks may hold all thread in limited pool while user wait some quick action in UI

Different thread pools (one pool for one type of task):
➕ thread pool of long-running tasks can accumulate task while quick task can be  executed in their own thread pool in-depend
➕ you know everything about tasks in your application - you can fine-tune pool size for every type of task, setup threads priority, initial stack size etc. with thread factory
➕ if you define thread group and thread name, it can help you in debug
➖ have different thread pools involve to hard control their life cycle
➖ this implementation will not give a lot of benefits in poor separation by tasks classes

Any case, you need some compromise and an assessment of the advantages

Comment: suppose I have 5 different type of task and there own thread pool when i  initialize these thread pool with min and maximum `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` is Couse performance problem? in android

Comment: `availableProcessors()` only makes sense for CPU-bound tasks. It's irrelevant for blocking tasks.

Comment: @SKPanchal a lot of threads, of course, are not very good, but we need to remember that the system any case give time to work for every thread depending on priority. This means that short tasks in their own pool will not get stuck in the queue and as soon as it posible they will be processed

Answer (score 0):

Talking teorically i think you can do that and according to [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) should be improve your performance:

> Thread pools address two different problems: they usually provide
>   improved performance when executing large numbers of asynchronous
>   tasks, due to reduced per-task invocation overhead, and they provide a
>   means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads,
>   consumed when executing a collection of tasks. Each ThreadPoolExecutor
>   also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed
>   tasks.